# Python datetime in reverse

Tags: python, datetime

```
y=(datetime.datetime.now() ).strftime("%y%m%d")
```

gives `'110418'`

I have data that reads '110315' and '110512', not trying to create it.

How do I change  `'110418'` into date time so I can subtract

from `'2011-07-15'` (str)

```
import datetime

t = datetime.datetime.today()
print type(t)

tdate =datetime.datetime.strptime('110416', '%y%m%d') 
print type(tdate)

d =t-tdate
print d
```

gives me

```
3 days, 15:14:38.921000
```

I need just "3".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert any string representation into a datetime object using the `strptime` method.

Here's an example converting your string above into a datetime object:

```
import datetime

my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-07-15', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Now you'll have a datetime object which can be subtracted against other datetime objects naturally.

If you're subtracting two dates, Python produces a `datetime.timedelta` object. You can then strip all of this away to just the days by doing `print d.days` in your example above.

For further info on what you can do with the datetime library, see: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Comment: Using: Dif = datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-07-15', '%Y-%m-%d') - datetime.datetime.strptime('110715', '%y%m%d'), thanks

Comment: How would I No. days only not date and time?

Comment: You can convert a `datetime` object to a `date` object by calling `datetime.date()`. In the example above, that would be `my_date.date()`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not completely sure I understood your question, but if you want to parse a string into a time object, you can use strptime:

```
import time
time.strptime('2011-07-15', '%Y-%m-%d')
```